# How to programatically delete Azure Active Directory user?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-active-directory

I am using the following code.
The code executes fine but does not delete the user.

```
IUser deleteuser = new User();
deleteuser = users.Where(myuser => myuse

r.MailNickname.Equals("IshanArora")).FirstOrDefault();

if (deleteuser != null)
{
    deleteuser.DeleteAsync();
}
```

Comment: What client library are you using? Did you confirm that the deletion request is actually being made to AAD (i.e. does the `if` condition evaluate to `true`)?

Comment: We are using active directory library and calling graph api. Yes the if condition evaluates to true.

Comment: What error condition are you seeing?  Do you have a fiddler trace to see what's happening on the wire?  Are you making the call in the context of a signed in user or in app-only context?

Comment: Yes i am getting this .Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

Comment: have you seen this? https://github.com/AzureADSamples/ConsoleApp-GraphAPI-DotNet/issues/5

Comment: For testing purposes, have you considered performing the deletion synchronously instead of asynchronously so that you can debug the code more easily?

Answer (score 1):

I am deleting users by retrieving it before deleting it:

```
private async Task DeleteUser()
{
    ActiveDirectoryClient client = AuthenticationHelper.GetActiveDirectoryClient();

    // Retrieve user from its displayname
    var user = await client.Users.Where(u => u.DisplayName == "user two").ExecuteSingleAsync();

    // Or Retrieve user from its principal name
    // var user = await client.Users.Where(u => u.UserPrincipalName== "user two").ExecuteSingleAsync();

    // Or Retrieve user from its id in the directory
    //var user = await client.Users.GetByObjectId("0b34c995-0970-4776-ae87-f66d384f9c45").ExecuteAsync();

    // Delete the user
    await user.DeleteAsync();
}
```

**You should notice that it may takes few seconds before seeing that the user is deleted from the Azure portal**

Comment: While I am doing this same but i can't able to delete the user form my website via the graph api and loggedin user is global admin.

Comment: What are the permission of you application in the azure ad ?

Comment: My permissions are.
Read directory data ,View users' basic profile
Read and write directory data  
Read and write all users' full profiles  
Create, read, update and delete user tasks and projects (preview) 
View users' email address  
Read and write all users' full profiles  
Read and write access to user profile  
Read and write directory data  
Enable sign-on and read users' profiles  
Read directory data  
Read and write directory data  
Read all users' full profiles  
Read all users' basic profiles